# Android rectangle document detection using opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I use the OpenCV library for detecting a white page from a book. Finding 4 corners on dark surfaces, but the white background finds only 3 corners. How can I find a way to find 4 corners or read a page on a white background?

Or could you suggest another library that I can use outside of Opencv?

I use the following code to find the contours.

```
Mat grayImage = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
Mat cannedImage = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
Mat dilate = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);

Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageMat, imageMat, new Size(3, 3), 0);
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayImage, grayImage, new Size(5.0, 5.0), 0.0);
Imgproc.threshold(grayImage, grayImage, 20.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_TRIANGLE);
Imgproc.Canny(grayImage, cannedImage, 75.0, 200.0);
Imgproc.dilate(cannedImage, dilate, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(10.0, 10.0)));
```

How can I change this code?

I test my code with these photos.

[image]

[image]